# JQuery + setTimeout won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've got a problem: I want to move an object from left to right for 1px every second, but it won't work and I cannot find a reason. I've read multiple threads in here and did it exactly like it was recommended. This is my JS code. i is just an iterator. But the whole code is executed at once and the browser is crashing!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        setTimeout(moveIt(i), 1000);
        function moveIt(i) {
            console.log(i);
            if (i < 10)
                $("#moveObj").css('left', ($("#moveObj").css('left')+1)+"px");
            else if (i >= 10 && i < 20)
                $("#moveObj").css('left', ($("#moveObj").css('left')-1)+"px");
            else
                i = -1;

            i++;
            setTimeout(moveIt(i), 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no `else if` in JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first parameter of setTimeout is your problem, you can do this:

```
setTimeout('moveIt('+i+')', 1000);
```

first paramter could be a string or a function, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ moveIt(i); }, 1000);
```

But keep in mind that using first alternative which is one of `eval` situations, is not a good practice.([Eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx))

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Didn't think about that, and all the examples and recommandations had no functions with parameters. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function which will be executed after delay. See [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(function(){
   moveIt(i);
}, 1000);
```

### OR

You can pass a string of code you want to execute after delay

```
setTimeout('moveIt('+i+')', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout expects a function (or a string but then it'll eval it and that's not a good thing). You can have a function called moveIt return a function:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        var moveIt=function(i) {
          return function(){
            console.log(i);
            if (i < 10)
                $("#moveObj").css('left', ($("#moveObj").css('left')+1)+"px");
            else if (i >= 10 && i < 20)
                $("#moveObj").css('left', ($("#moveObj").css('left')-1)+"px");
            else
                i = -1;

            i++;
            setTimeout(moveIt(i), 1000);
          };
        }
        setTimeout(moveIt(i), 1000);
    });
```